# Logging GIMP 2.10 commands for script development?

Tags: scripting, gimp

I'm trying to write some GIMP 2.10+ scripts as "actions" to help speed up my processes. I did this back in 2.4 era, then took a long break and now I'm very out-of-date.

Is it possible to log the GIMP commands (plus arguments) fired click-by-click to a file or window somewhere, as an assist to GIMPScript development? I of course have the procedure browser and "search and run a command" but it's very slow going when I'm not sure what I even need to look for in some cases.

Comment: Not as far as I know. It wouldn't be too useful anyway because the mapping being UI actions and API entries is usually not so direct (especially in 2.10 with all the GEGL-based plugins). But the procedure browser rarely deceived me. And in the dire cases you can always ask here.

Comment: Well shoot. 
Submit that as an answer so I can mark it :)

Comment: My pleasure....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not as far as I know. It wouldn't be too useful anyway because the mapping being UI actions and API entries is usually not so direct (especially in 2.10 with all the GEGL-based plugins). But the procedure browser rarely deceived me. And in the dire cases you can always ask here.